Why did Geordi have his visor replaced with ocular implants between Generations and First Contact?
In First Contact, Geordi is not wearing his VISOR and instead has ocular implants. In the previous movie, Generations, Geordi still has his VISOR for the whole movie. Why did he change?

In-universe technological advancements. You can see from the brief shot in FC that his vision is more "normal" than it was with the visor. Same way we are now moving towards artificial eyes now. Why wouldn't people take this option?

The captain probably insisted after Geordi returned in Generations and the crew decided to play stupid in assuming everything was okay with his VISOR (leading to the destruction of the ship).

@HamSandwich funny but unrealistic

@LogicDictates Sorry. I did not intend to remove the [star-trek] tag I was just trying to change the body and rolled it back to the revision before your revision. It was an unintended 'side effect' of rolling back the question to before your edit.

@LogicDictates I just don't like adding Star Trek to the beginning of things, I did it because I asked why he had his VISOR replaced with ocular implants not what motivated him too, and no.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Katherine Pulaski offered Geordi the options of ocular implants or the regeneration of his optic nerve all the way back in TNG season 2. At the time, he didn't seem keen on the ocular implants, as they would've reduced his visual range by twenty percent.

PULASKI: It's possible to install optical devices which look like normal eyes, and would still give you about the same visual range as the visor.
LAFORGE: Done? You say almost. How much reduction?
PULASKI: Twenty percent. There is another option. I can attempt to regenerate your optic nerve, and, with the help of the replicator, fashion normal eyes. You would see like everyone else.
LAFORGE: Wait a minute. I was told that was impossible.
PULASKI: I've done it twice, in situations somewhat similar to yours. Geordi, it would eliminate the constant pain you are under. Why are you hesitating?
LAFORGE: Well, when I came to see you, it was to talk about modifying this. And now you're saying it could be possible for me to have normal vision?
PULASKI: Yes.
LAFORGE: I don't know. I'd be giving up a lot.
PULASKI: There's something else you must know. This is a one shot. If you decide to change your mind, there's no going back. And there are risks. I can offer choices, not guarantees.
LAFORGE: Well, this is a lot to think about. I'll get back to you, Doctor. Thank you.

Star Trek: The Next Generation - S02E05 - "Loud As A Whisper"

Evidently, Geordi stuck with the VISOR until some time between Star Trek: Generations and Star Trek: First Contact -- so, between six and eight years later, in-universe -- at which point, he chose to go with ocular implants. I don't believe any official source has ever explained why he went with the ocular implants at that specific point in time, although, given that six-plus years had passed since he was first offered them, it's possible that the technology had improved, making them a more attractive option.
It's also worth noting that in Star Trek: Generations, Geordi was captured by Tolian Soran and some rogue Klingons, including the Duras sisters, Lursa and B'Etor. They modified his VISOR to transmit a video signal to the main viewscreen on the bridge of their Bird-of-Prey, through which they ascertained the Enterprise-D's shield modulation, enabling them to bypass its shields and ultimately destroy it.

LURSA: That's it! Replay from time index nine two four. ...Magnify this section and enhance. ...Their shields are operating on a modulation of two five seven point four.
B'ETOR: Adjust our torpedo frequency to match two five seven point four!

Star Trek: Generations (1994)

While we lack official confirmation that the VISOR's role in the destruction of the Enterprise-D influenced Geordi's decision to replace it with ocular implants, the relative timing of those events fits nicely with that theory, and it's hard to believe that he and Starfleet wouldn't have started to view the VISOR as a liability after such a catastrophic security breach.

good answer. It could use some improvement because it is a theory. But I don't really care.

One has to wonder if the "visual range" he'd give up is greater field of view. Given it wraps around his head, it's very possible the VISOR has better-than-human field of view, whereas implants would obviously be limited by skull anatomy in that respect.

@Matthew I can't say with certainty, but given what we know about the VISOR's capabilities (see the quote in Andrew's answer) I think it's much more likely that it's about the ability to see things outside the visible spectrum rather than about simple field of view. Geordi enjoys that advantage he gets as compensation for his disability, and uses it to good effect in his engineering job.

It could also be that implant technology had advanced enough at that point in time that Geordi could feel comfortable with getting the implants, but without having to give up any of his visual range.

I'm not sure it has ever been spelled out in universe, but out of universe LeVar Burton explained in an interview:

It was time. Eighty percent of my vision was cut off when I wore that thing, and it physically hurt, which was one of the more important reasons I wanted to get out from underneath it. We held on to it for so long, because, as Rick says, it was one of the ways that we established in the minds of the audience the technology of the twenty-fourth century.
On the series it became problematic because it was cost prohibitive. We were never able to show the audience what Geordi saw, because it was too expensive and we were on a tight budget. So it became a barrier to storytelling, physically painful for me, and on a spiritual level, it’s really just a sin to cover an actor’s eyes.
I wasn’t really aware of how much of a barrier it had become until we shot this movie, and in the absence of the VISOR, I noticed that the other actors were relating to me very differently. They were engaging me in a way that they never did in scenes. So the visor is dead; long live the visor!


"We were never able to show the audience what Geordi saw, because it was too expensive" - ironically, by the time of First Contact, this should gradually have stopped to be an obstacle thanks to CGI (the effect we saw the one time we did see what Geordi sees, in "Heart of Glory", was not that impressive).

One would expect the studio to provide an ergonomic prop. But who am I to know?

@MindwinRememberMonica: You can't make an ergonomic VISOR without a level of CGI that did not exist at the time. It has to squeeze the actor's head, or else it will fall off. In-universe, it was supposed to physically connect to implants in Geordi's temples, but obviously they were not going to implant LeVar Burton with magnets.

I can't help but wonder if there was some way they could have used something like spirit gum or the adhesive they use to attach ECG electrodes to help hold it on, so that it didn't have to pinch so hard. Serious kudos to Burton for delivering a performance for so many episodes while in that discomfort, without ever letting on.

@Kevin why do you think that a prop needs to squeeze the actor's head "or else it will fall off"??? Skin-safe adhesives exist at least since 1920 (when the Band-Aid was invented).

@O.R.Mapper hm I thought I remembered an episode where they showed some false colour image as his view...

@PlasmaHH: Yes, exactly. As I said, even if that would have been expensive to do when TNG was produced for TV for some reason, by the time ST:FC was in production, image processing software was becoming well capable of recoloring/blurring series of video frames.

@HenningKockerback good answer but purely out-of-universe I would prefer an in-universe reason but if out-of-universe is all there is it's all there is.

@anaximander I was using spirit gum for a 4 days LARP. It is "safe" but honestly it was so unpleasant I have never wore that mask again. It burns, it leaves unpleasant residue, it made me cry with the solvent it released when drying. I'll never use it next to eyes again. So yea, it is not a simple choice and drawback-free solution.

@Mołot I'm aware there are drawbacks, but I the Star Trek props and costume folks are no strangers to parts and prosthetics that are stuck and glued on in various ways, including several that are quite close to eyes. I've never heard that the Klingon forehead ridges were painful to wear, for example, or any of the Borg facial attachments (eg. 7-of-9's were quite close to her eye). I just find it curious that a show so familiar with sticking things to actors' faces couldn't find a way for that visor to stay put without it physically squeezing his head with enough force to be painful.

@anaximander 7 of 9 first appeared 10 years later than La Forge, so that's not quite fair comparison. And her implant is relatively small and close to the skin. Forehead ridges have much more of a flat contact with face available, so mounting is easier. They can also be soft and don't protrude so much away from the face.

Wow those are some interesting... coincidences.  80% of his vision was impaired, versus the 20% reduction (in-universe) that getting rid of it would have caused.  But more importantly, wearing the prop actually hurt, while in universe it also hurt. I always found it interesting that Geordi was not constantly cranky from the constant pain, but @anaximander learning the Burton managed to hide it adds an interesting aspect to the whole thing.

I recall during ST:TNG's first run seeing a clip of an interview with somebody (possibly LeVar Burton's agent?) lamenting that the show chose to hide not just an actor's eyes  but LeVar Burton's eyes, which the interviewee considered essential to his powerful performance in Roots.

In-universe, Geordi's VISOR causes him constant pain.
From "Encounter at Farpoint":

LAFORGE: Is a remarkable piece of bio-electronic engineering by which I quote see much of the EM spectrum ranging from simple heat and infrared through radio waves et cetera, et cetera, and forgive me if I've said and listened to this a thousand times before.
(Without the Visor, Geordi La Forge's eyes are white sightless orbs, and he has flashing red lights at his temples)
CRUSHER: You've been blind all your life?
LAFORGE: I was born this way.
CRUSHER: And you've felt pain all the years that you've used this?
LAFORGE: They say it's because I use my natural sensors in different ways.

So as soon as an alternative was possible, Geordi would have a strong reason to switch as soon as possible.
Geordi had been offered some means of eliminating the pain, but they are risky and/or would interfere with vision. From the same episode:

CRUSHER: Well, I see two choices. The first is painkillers.
LAFORGE: Which would affect how this works. No. Choice number two?
CRUSHER: Exploratory surgery. Desensitise the brain areas troubling you.
LAFORGE: Same difference. No, thank you, Doctor.
CRUSHER: I understand.


In the deuterocanonical Trek Litverse (specifically The Insolence of Office) it was because of security concerns following the events of Generations in which his VISOR was hacked and used to aid in the destruction of the Enterprise-D, and coupled with the previous incident of VISOR-based brainwashing in The Mind's Eye.
La Forge was ordered by Admiral Hayes (of various screen appearances) to replace his VISOR as a security risk or be reassigned to a less-sensitive post.

La Forge was tempted to tell the admiral that, no, he wouldn’t pardon the expression. But he restrained himself, and said instead, “Sir, I have had this VISOR for over thirty years. It’s a part of who I am. You can’t force me to give it up.”
“No, Mr. La Forge, I can’t force you,” Hayes said. “However, should you elect not to comply with Starfleet’s current security standards, you would not be able to continue to serve aboard the Enterprise.”


this is based on non-canon sources I would prefer to have canon sources as the answer to my question.

This answer could be improved by adding info about TNG incidents where his visor was hacked and he was kidnapped/tortured because of his disability.  I think there's relevant canon background.
